# JMeter Constant Throughput Timer

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter Testplan which tests approx 20 different requests. For each request to be tested I want to specify a different constant throughput timer. E. g. Request 1 has constant throughtput of 10 / min and request 2 has constant throughput of 5 / min.
However, the constant throughput timer always overrides the next one so that the constant throughput timers are not individual for each request.
[image: This is my implementation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the requests are in the same Thread Group. As there are no logical controllers in the test plan requests are executed one after another. When Constant Throughput Timers are introduced as child to the request JMeter tries to create request to maintain the specified throughput if server can handle them.

Subsequent requests are executed once the previous requests are executed. Hence throughput cannot be generated as specified.

If there is no dependency among the requests throughput can controlled by organizing the requests across independent Thread Groups.

Comment: Great. Happy Testing !

Answer (score 2):

In order to effect only specific request add Timer **under** request.

This is due to [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Answer (score 1):

The "slowest" Constant Throughput Timer will slow down the other requests as JMeter waits for the previous sampler completion prior to starting the next one.

So if you need to execute Samplers with different throughput you need to place them under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

If you will need to pass data between thread groups it can be done in 2 ways:

1. By calling [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in one thread group to write data into a Java Property which can be read anywhere else via [__P( ) function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
2. By using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)